# Too many results after executing a powershell script with foreach loops

Tags: powershell, loops

I'm just starting my journey with Powershell and I'm doing some basic scripting, starting with a foreach and if, elseif constructs.

I have a problem with foreach loops.

I tried to write a simple code with a parameter given by user. I have a CSV file with 2 columns: Zenskie (female) and Meskie (male) filled with names. My code is to find the name given by user in the CSV and as an output give an information about the gender.

Part of the CSV file:

```
Zenskie;Meskie
Ada;Aaron
Adamina;Abdon
Adela;Abel
Adelajda;Abelard
Adriana;Abraham
Adrianna;Achilles
Agata;Adam
Agnieszka;Adelard
Aida;Adnan
Bogna;Dawid
```

I added also a little twist for my wife - there should be a special comment just for her name and here I have a problem. The outcome is as it should be but it's shown multiple times (I'm guessing as many as the rows in the CSV).

I also tried to add an "else" part at the end, if the input given by user was not present on the list. But when I did that it gives results from the previous "elseif".

I tried to use another elseif with "elseif ($UserName -ne $Man) but it also gives me the wrong answer.

I bet I'm missing something easy here...

---

```bsh
Param (
  [string]$UserName = (Read-Host " Tell me your name ")
)

$Names = Import-Csv -Path C:\Powershell\Moje_nowe\Lista_imion3.csv -Delimiter ";"

ForEach ($item in $Names) {
  $Women = $item.("Zenskie")
  $Man = $item.("Meskie")
  if ($UserName -eq $Women) {
    Write-Output "$UserName you are women!"
  }
  elseif ($UserName -eq $Man) {
    Write-Output "$UserName you are man!"
  }
  elseif ($UserName -eq "Bogna") {
    Write-Output "Kiss me!! :)"
  }
  else {
    Write-Output "$UserName you have an odd name"
  }
}
```

---

Expected result:

for input Bogna:

```
Tell me your name: bogna

Kiss me!! :)
```

Actual result:

```
Kiss me!! :)

Kiss me!! :)

Kiss me!! :)
```

and so on

When I add the part when the input is not on the list:

Expected:

```
Tell me your name: bdsdsd


bdsdsd you have an odd name
```

Actual:

no matter what I put as an input

```
bdsdsd you have an odd name

bdsdsd you have an odd name

bdsdsd you have an odd name
```

and so on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :

```
Param ([string]$UserName = (Read-Host " Tell me your name " ))

#if Bogna, not necessary to loop, print and out
if ($UserName -eq "Bogna")
{
   "Kiss me!! :)  (nice declaration)"
   return
}

#loop on all elements and if you found as you want, break for not continue ==> attention break leave the programm in pipe foreach
$FirstElement=Import-csv -Path "C:\Powershell\Moje_nowe\Lista_imion3.csv" -Delimiter ";" | %{

    if ($_.Zenskie -eq $UserName)
    {
        "$UserName you are women!"

        break
    }
    elseif ($_.Meskie -eq $UserName)
    {
        "$UserName you are man!"

        break
    }

}

# BE CAREFULL IF BREAK IS RAISED THE SCRIPT IS ENDED AND THIS CODE DOESNT EXECUTED
if (! $FirstElement)
{
"$UserName you have an odd name, Brrrrr !"
}
```

If your script continue after csv loop, for dont leave script with break you can do it :

```
Param ([string]$UserName = (Read-Host " Tell me your name " ))

#if Bogna, not necessary to loop, print and out
if ($UserName -eq "Bogna")
{
   "Kiss me!! :)  (nice declaration)"
   return
}

#loop on all elements and if you found as you want, break for not continue
$FirstElement=$null

$allElement=Import-csv -Path "C:\Powershell\Moje_nowe\Lista_imion3.csv" -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($item in $allElement)
{
     if ($item.Zenskie -eq $UserName)
    {
        "$UserName you are women!"
        $FirstElement=$item
        break
    }
    elseif ($item.Meskie -eq $UserName)
    {
        "$UserName you are man!"
        $FirstElement=$item
        break
    }
}

#if not element founded
if (! $FirstElement)
{
    "$UserName you have an odd name, Brrrrr !"
}
```

Comment: `break` is the wrong command to use, because - in the absence of an enclosing loop - it _exits the script as a whole_; `break` can _not_ be used to exit a pipeline - short of using `break` _with a dummy loop_ around the pipeline, there is currently no way to exit a pipeline prematurely - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821. In short: your code _happens to_ work, but only because no code after the loop needs to run in this case; if there were additional code to run, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "do ... until" loop to keep the game running ... ;-)

```
$CSV = @'
Zenskie;Meskie
Ada;Aaron
Adamina;Abdon
Adela;Abel
Adelajda;Abelard
Adriana;Abraham
Adrianna;Achilles
Agata;Adam
Agnieszka;Adelard
Aida;Adnan
Bogna;Dawid
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

do {
    $UserName = Read-Host " Tell me your name (End with 'quit')" 
    if ($UserName -eq 'Bogna') { "Kiss me!! :)" }
    elseif ($UserName -in $CSV.Zenskie) { "$UserName you are woman!" }
    elseif ($UserName -in $CSV.Meskie) { "$UserName you are man!" }
    else  { "$UserName you have an odd name" }
} until ($Username -eq 'quit')
```

Answer (score 1):

> The outcome is as it should be, but it's shown multiple times (I'm guessing as many as the rows in the CSV).

Indeed: Given that you loop over the objects imported from the CSV rows individually, the `if` statement is evaluated *for each*.

**Use `break` to exit the loop once you've found a match in the `if` and `elseif` branches** to fix that (but not in the `else` branch, because it must potentially wait for *all* objects to be examined in order to infer that no match was found).

**Caveat**: **Only use `break` in a `foreach` *loop* (statement) (as in your question), not in the *pipeline* with the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*** (as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58143772/45375)). In the latter case, `break` looks for an *enclosing loop* on the call stack, and if it finds none, *exits the script as whole*.
In short: **Only ever use `break` and `continue` in *loops* (`foreach`, `while`, ...) or `switch` statements**; `break` and `continue` are entirely unrelated to pipelines (but you can use `return` in a `ForEach-Object` script block to skip to the *next* pipeline input object).

<sup>As of PowerShell v7, there is no direct support for breaking out of (exiting) a *pipeline* on demand; adding such support is being requested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).</sup>

However, it is **much simpler and more efficient to take advantage of [`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)** PowerShell's, array-membership-test (containment) operator (PSv3+; in PSv2, or alternatively, use `-contains` where the operand order is reversed), which **allows you to perform a *single* test (per comparison value) across all CSV rows**, as also shown in [Olaf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142436/45375).

A simplified example:

<sup>Note: The code below reads all CSV data into memory first, and then creates two arrays from it, for the values in the two columns. For a file with a list of first names, this shouldn't be a memory concern; when dealing with large input data sets, however, you may need a solution that processes the input CSV file row by row in the pipeline.</sup>

```
# Parse sample CSV input into objects with .Zenskie and .Meskie properties.
$names = @'
Zenskie;Meskie
Ada;Aaron
Adamina;Abdon
Adela;Abel
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

# Extract the male and female names into individual arrays.
# Note how no quoting is needed to acces the properties (columns) by names
# and how accessing a property on the input array ($names) automatically
# returns the property values *from all array elements*, a feature known
# as member enumeration.
$maleNames = $names.Meskie
$femaleNames = $names.Zenskie

# Test a few sample names.
'Abdon', 'Bogna', 'Adela', 'Bill' | ForEach-Object {

  if ($_ -eq 'Bogna') { # exception
    "Pocałuj mnie!! :)"
  }
  elseif ($_ -in $maleNames) { # -in tests presence in the array, case-insensitively
    "$_, you are a man."
  }
  elseif ($_ -in $femaleNames) {    
    "$_, you are a woman."
  }
  else {
    "$_, you have an odd name."
  }

}
```

The above yields:

```
Abdon, you have are a man.
Pocałuj mnie!! :)
Adela, you have are a woman.
Bill, you have an odd name.
```

Comment: I still +1 your proposal, even if it is counterproductive on large files. You walk all the lines 2 times and store everything in memory and for each name you want to test you potentially test all men and potentials all women to find your solution, rather than browse the list of csv once and test all of your names for each line (in general, the quantity of what you are looking for is much lower than the set in which you search for it in computer science, especially with CSV)

Comment: @Esperento57: Thanks for updating your answer; re design decision: I agree that it is unfortunate, but the problem is that changing the behavior now could break existing code. Re large files: yes, but we're dealing with a list of first names here, which is unlikely to be too large to fit into memory or take long to load; however, I've added a note to the answer.